# search in specific region in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab, str-replace, text-processing

I'm going to replace special word in a text file in matlab but just the words that are in brackets"[]" not all the words. for example I have a text like this:

```
this is a [test]
I'm going to replace just test in [] not the other [test].
```

I'm going to replace word **test**  with **test 1**. the result should be:

```
this is a [test1]
I'm going to replace just test in [] not the other [test1].
```

Do I need to push and pop the brackets? or there is simple way?

Comment: What should happen for `this is a [test asdf]` ? Does it become `this is a [test1 asdf]`?

Comment: yes, become as you wrote.

Comment: Will there be nested brackets?

Comment: Will there be multiple occurrences of your special word inside the brackets? `[test test]`?

Comment: there is no nested brackets and there is just one special word in barckets. your answer is wonderful. thnax

Comment: @knedlsepp as  get enough reputation I'll do it. I click it but it turns back!! believe me :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on regular expressions, so I couldn't do it with a single expression:

I will assume the same notation as *hbaderts*:

```
txt = 'I''m going to replace just test in [] not the other [test] but still [asdf test test asdf].';
word = 'test';
newWord = 'test1';
```

### Replace all occurrences inside the brackets:

This first finds matching brackets and then extracts the data into cells via `arrayfun`, uses `strrep` to replace your words and then concatenates the cells again.

```
%%// Find all opening and matching closing brackets
[start,stop] = regexp(txt,'\[[^\]]*\]');
%%// Separate the data into cells: 
foundBrackets = arrayfun(@(b,e) txt(b:e), start, stop, 'uni', 0);
beforefoundBrackets = arrayfun(@(b,e) txt(b:e),  [1,stop(1:end-1)+1],start-1, 'uni', 0);
%%// Replace the data in the bracket cells:
replacedBrackets = strrep(foundBrackets, word, newWord);
newTxtinCells = [reshape([beforefoundBrackets;replacedBrackets],1,[]),txt(stop(end)+1:end)];
%%// Cat cells
newTxt = cat(2,newTxtinCells{:});
```

### Replace single occurrence inside brackets:

In this case a single regular expression will do:

```
newTxt = regexprep(txt,['\[([^\]]*)',word,'([^\]]*)\]'],['\[$1',newWord,'$2\]'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This demands for regular expressions (`regexp`). I myself am not an expert, but let me show you one way to do it (though there may be more elegant solutions):

Use a `regexp` to find all occurrences of `test` within in brackets:

```
regexp(txt,['\[[^\]]*(',word,')[^\]]*\]']);
```

- `\[` to start with a [
- `[^\]]*` for any number of characters which are not a `]`
- `(`, `)` only for grouping
- `word` is what you are looking for.
- `[^\]]*` again, for any number of characters which are not a `]`
- `\]` to end with a ]

You can verify that it finds the correct occurrences (for the example below) with:

```
regexp(txt,['\[[^\]]*(',word,')[^\]]*\]'],'match')
ans = 
    '[test]'    '[asdf test asdf]'
```

With `tokenExtents` instead, you will get a cell array where each cell is a vector `[start,end]`. With these, you can now replace the words.

```
% Create example
txt = 'I''m going to replace just test in [] not the other [test] but still [asdf test asdf].';
word = 'test';
newWord = 'test1';

% Find all occurrences with regexp
ind = regexp(txt,['\[[^\]]*(',word,')[^\]]*\]'],'tokenExtents');

% Build new string
newTxt = txt(1:ind{1}(1)-1);  % first part
for k=1:size(ind,2)-1         % all middle parts
    newTxt = [newTxt,newWord,txt(ind{k}(2)+1:ind{k+1}(1)-1)];
end
newTxt = [newTxt,newWord,txt(ind{k+1}(2)+1:end)]; % last part
```

Disclaimer: I have to admit that especially building the string could be nicer. Maybe somebody comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Hm. Your solution suffers from the same problem I'm currently dealing with: multiple occurences of the search-word inside a single pair of brackets are not replaced...

Comment: This is my current solution, that will only replace the last occurence of test in each pair of brackets... `regexprep('this is a [fooo blabla test test]','\[([^\]]*)test([^\]]*)\]','\[$1test1$2\]')`

Comment: You are right, this is a major issue... I was trying to achieve sth like your solution but didn't know about the `$` statements. Nice solution so far!

Comment: @nasirkhani I agree, his solution is very elegant. If you like his answer, consider upvoting it as recognition for his efforts.